# Is context menu strip possible in VB.net console app?

Tags: vb.net, console

Hi Stackoverflow members
Is context menu strip possible in vb.net console application
Im not using any code thats why I didnt puplished the code (sorry for that)
Please let me know , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change the context menu of a console, as far as I'm aware. This isn't a .NET limitation - it's just a matter of the app running within a console, and it doesn't get to modify the window menus.

Often console apps that need their own menus embed them *within* the console. See the screenshots of [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic) for an example of this. It's feasible to do all of that within VB... although I'd start looking for a "console management" .NET library at that point. (I don't know of one, but I'd be surprised if there really wasn't one.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton whoops you are right, I misunderstood. Deleting...